# Powershell add group to all (onelevel) OUs

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

i need to add a Group "admins" to all onelevel OUs via powershell.
Is there any quick command? quest active roles is possible.

thank you.

my idea was like:

```
$test=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' -searchscope onelevel | FT Name | ForEach-Object{ Add-QADPermission -"$test" -Account "administrators"  -ApplyTo ChildObjects -Rights genericall}
```

Error Message: Add-QADPermission : Account name is too long.

Comment: What do you mean by adding a group to an OU ? Create a new group in each OU ?

Comment: to Add an existing group to Each ou (no subtrees)

Comment: But a group can just exists once !

Comment: sorry i mean add the group to all ou acls with genericall